# Empty String Checkbox value on checked

Tags: html

The value in checkbox is empty string at server side even though I Put the value as 1 in input tag and checked the checkbox and submitted the form.

```
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" id="organisationdetails" name="organisationdetails"   value="1">Organisation Details </label>
</div>
```

Comment: how you fetch the value?

Comment: Please make sure there is no other input tag named as "organisationdetails" in your entire form. Sometimes it happens.

Comment: <form method="POST" id="petitionerform" action="insertPetitioner.do" accept-charset="utf-8">

I use Struts 1.3 to get the form value String org=pf.getOrganisationdetails();

Comment: @ManishJangir did checked by renaming it does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can try jquery for value changes and your checkbox have value 1 but its not checked with checkbox checked option.

```
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" id="organisationdetails" name="organisationdetails" value="1" checked="checked">Organisation Details </label>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
     el = $(this);
     el.val((el.prop('checked') == true) ? '1' : '0');
     if(el.prop('checked') == true){
            el.attr('checked', true);
     }else{
            el.removeAttr('checked', false);
     }
});
</script>
```

Here i have made a [example](https://jsfiddle.net/s92hz16j/20/).

Comment: yes, it works you have to add `checked="checked"` in checkbox option because your value by default `1`.

Comment: I don't want by default checked.

Comment: then just remove value option from your checkbox and try to post.